# Selenium RC tool giving exception for opening secure http page

Tags: selenium, certificate, selenium-rc

I am going to automate a process which is basically based on browser. I have written a script to automate the process and it is working fine.

When the script is going to open HTTPS :(Secure page), it is not opening the page, because of a security exception. It is asking for a security certificate and I am adding it successfully.

And after that it opens the page successfully. But the main problem is that it is asking to add the certificate every time when i am opening the secure page ().

Any resolution for removing the certificate issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote up an article on this topic a couple weeks back.  Hopefully it helps you out:

http://mogotest.com/blog/2010/04/13/how-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-selenium

-- 
Kevin